# Change size of arrows using matplotlib quiver

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using quiver from matplotlib to plot a vectorial field. I would like to 
change the size of the thickness of each arrow depending on 
the number of data which produced a specific arrow of the vector field. Therefore 
what I am looking for is not a general scale transformation of the arrow size, but the way 
to customize the thickness of the arrow in quiver one-by-one. 
Is it possible? Can you help me?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `linewidths` parameter to `plt.quiver` controls the thickness of the arrows. If you pass it a 1-dimensional array of values, each arrow gets a different thickness.

For example,

```
widths = np.linspace(0, 2, X.size)
plt.quiver(X, Y, cos(deg), sin(deg), linewidths=widths)
```

creates linewidths growing from 0 to 2.

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
sin = np.sin
cos = np.cos

# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370742/#6372413
xmax = 4.0
xmin = -xmax
D = 20
ymax = 4.0
ymin = -ymax
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, D)
y = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, D)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
# plots the vector field for Y'=Y**3-3*Y-X
deg = np.arctan(Y ** 3 - 3 * Y - X)
widths = np.linspace(0, 2, X.size)
plt.quiver(X, Y, cos(deg), sin(deg), linewidths=widths)
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

Comment: This breaks down if you we specify face colors that aren't your line color. Use the `width` keyword instead.

Comment: Also see: ["Linewidth(s) keywords not working with quiver"](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8630) -- github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib

Answer (score 6):

@unutbu's solution is not useful after matplotlib 2.0.0 (see [this issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8630) and [this pull request](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/6904)). As of matplotlib 2.1.2, there seems to be no parameter of `plt.quiver` which officially supports one-by-one configuration of arrow widths. But some workarounds are remained.

#### Method 1

Just use Python's loop and the `width` parameter. This will be slow for large data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# original code by user423805
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/6372413/5989200
xmax = 4.0
xmin = -xmax
D = 20
ymax = 4.0
ymin = -ymax

for y in np.linspace(ymin, ymax, D):
    for x in np.linspace(xmin, xmax, D):
        deg = np.arctan(y ** 3 - 3 * y - x)
        w = 0.005 * (y - ymin) / (ymax - ymin)  # just example...
        plt.quiver(x, y, np.cos(deg), np.sin(deg), width=w)

plt.show()
```

[image: the result image of above code]

#### Method 2

This is only a workaround, but `linewidths` can be used if we set `edgecolors`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# original code by user423805
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/6372413/5989200
xmax = 4.0
xmin = -xmax
D = 20
ymax = 4.0
ymin = -ymax
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, D)
y = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, D)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
deg = np.arctan(Y ** 3 - 3 * Y - X)
widths = np.linspace(0, 2, X.size)
plt.quiver(X, Y, np.cos(deg), np.sin(deg), linewidths=widths, edgecolors='k')
plt.show()
```

[image: the result image of above code]

Note that efiring, one of maintainers of matplotlib, [said](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8630#issuecomment-301885921):

> So please use the `width` kwarg together with `units`; `linewidths` is only for controlling the outline thickness, when an outline of a different color is explicitly requested.