# Change size of vectorhead in 3D and how to draw an angle between vectors?

Tags: python, matplotlib, vector, 3d

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


plt3d = plt.figure().gca(projection='3d')

plt3d.quiver( [ 0 , 0 ] , [ 0 , 0 ] , [ 0 , 0 ] , [ 0 , 1 ], [ 0 , 0 ] , [ 1 , 0] , pivot = 'tail' , color = 'green' ) 

plt3d.set_xlim3d(-2,2)
plt3d.set_ylim3d(-2,2)
plt3d.set_zlim3d(-2,2)

plt.show()
```

Is there a way to change the appearance of the vectors? It seems like the attributes given in the doc are not working. I want to change the size of the arrowhead in particular but it would also nice to know how to control other functionalities like the width of the shaft e.g. 
Secondly, how can I draw an angle between the vectors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change size of arrows using matplotlib quiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701952/change-size-of-arrows-using-matplotlib-quiver)

Comment: No. This was in 2D. And I mentioned that the 2D controls do not seem to work.

Comment: The head size of quiver in 3D is still [an open issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11746).

Comment: Alrighty thanks. What'd be an alternative?