# How do I specify the order of plots in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've tried looking around to solve my issue, and some answers state that the `zorder` of Matplotlib have bugs and others say that it works for them. Regardless, here's the image and code that have been causing problems:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim(0, 7)
ax.set_ylim(0, 7)
ax.set_zlim(0, 7)
ax.view_init(elev=20, azim=32)

# u
ax.quiver(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, color='C0', arrow_length_ratio=0.1, 
label=r'$\vec{u}$', zorder=10)

# v
ax.quiver(0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, color='C1', arrow_length_ratio=0.1, 
label=r'$\vec{v}$', zorder=0)

plt.legend()
ax.set_xlabel(r'$x$', fontsize='large')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$y$', fontsize='large')
ax.set_zlabel(r'$z$', fontsize='large')

plt.show()
```

This code produces the following image:

[image]

I want the blue arrow to be on top of the orange one. Specifying the `zorder` doesn't seem to work. Would anybody be kind enough to give me some tips and advice?

Thanks.

Comment: `zorder` is ignored in 3D plots (which makes sense as you define z explicitly), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611023/3d-parametric-curve-in-matplotlib-does-not-respect-zorder-workaround). My first idea was to simply raise the blue error by a small quantity (e.g. 0.01), but the results are not convincing.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution, that would make you *U* vector stand out, is to change it's thickness so that it is slightly larger than vector *V*. The way to do it would be with `linewidths` argument, see [Change size of arrows using matplotlib quiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701952/change-size-of-arrows-using-matplotlib-quiver). In your case something like:

```
# u
ax.quiver(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, color='C0', arrow_length_ratio=0.1, linewidths=2.5,
label=r'$\vec{u}$', zorder=10) 

# v
ax.quiver(0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, color='C1', arrow_length_ratio=0.1, linewidths=1., 
label=r'$\vec{v}$', zorder=0)
```

Although, I realize that it might not be exactly what you want to do.